# Find theta notation for each time x=x+1 is executed for nested 'for' loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I need to find the theta notation for each time $x = x + 1$ is executed. Here is the problem:

```
   for i=1 to 2n

     for j=1 to n
  
       x=x+1
```

I am confused if $1$ to $2n$ is the same as $1$ to $n$ since both are going to infinity (I believe). Won't the $1$ to $n$ continue on forever since it is unknown what $n$ actually is?

Comment: Presumably, you are supposed to find the runtime as a function of $n$, i.e. get a bound of the form $\Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about what you mean by that. Since x is incremented every time the inner loop is done, won't the arithmetic sum just continue on and on before ever having the outer loop become i=2, 3, etc. ?

Comment: I would assume that $n$ is fixed, and calculate the runtime in terms of $n$. I would report that the runtime is $\Theta(2n^2)$ since $x = x + 1$ is executed $2n \cdot n = 2n^2$ times.

Comment: How would you express that as an arithmetic sum?